# Issue with the value stored in the array structure is being changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, angular

I have an object structure which contains one array field,on the front end part(Angular) I add the value to the array based on the selection and the object structure looks as follows

```
todayRates: 10
yesterdayRates: 5
to: Array(1)
0: [3]
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

but when I use this values in the backend code(Node) to save to the dB the array structure changes to an array within an array as `to: [[3]]`

[image]

why does the structure changes,what can I do so I can just have an array and values in it not array within an array i.e simple `to: [3]` and not `to: [[3]]`

on the frontEnd i'm adding the value to the array as follows

```
 this.V2.pact.to.push((this.pactList.list.filter((data) =>{return data.toList})).map((data)=>{ return data.id}));
```

Comment: If you convert to/from your database, perhaps you should look there.

Comment: @vanowm this change takes place before saving to dB

Comment: Than without seeing the code my best guess is you do something wrong...

Comment: @vanowm does it have to do anything with the way i'm adding the value to array on frontEnd

Comment: @vanowm i figured it ,it was due to the way i was adding the value to the array ,its sorted  when the push is changed  to as ((this.pactList.list.filter((data) =>{return data.toList})).map((data)=>{ this.V2.pact.to.push( data.id)}));

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = (this.pactList.list.filter(data => data.toList)).map(data=> data.id); 
this.V2.pact.to.push(...arr);
```

for me the result of your fonctions is an array. i add it into the variable `arr`
if you push the `arr` variable into your array you effectively have an array of array. if you want to destructure your array use `...arr` in the push fonction as above should work

Comment: you can do that directly in the map function ,where you can push the data in array ,Can you please look at the comment above and review

Comment: I know that you can push every element disctincly in your array :) but at the beginning you were trying to add an array in an other one so i proposed a solution that did the same trick